# Keras and AutoGraph

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

Reading [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/autograph#keras_and_autograph)  and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55171526/tensorflow-2-0-keras-is-training-4x-slower-than-2-0-estimator#comment97183315_55172506) I understood that with non-dynamical models on TensorFlow-2.0, Keras would use AutoGraph. But now writing a callback to get the variables' history during training,

```
class TrainHistory(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.vars = []

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.vars.append([v.numpy() for v in self.model.variables])
```

I see that the `.numpy()` method of eager tensors can be used. I was expecting an error like `numpy() is only available when eager execution is enabled`. Is one executing eager code when using Keras with TensorFlow-2.0?

[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/autograph#the_tffunction_decorator) it's mentioned that for compute-intensive functions like convolutions there's not much speed up of `tf.function`-decorated functions compared to eager code, but from the numbers shown in the example I guess that the difference could be significative for long trainings. Would it be better performance-wise to use `GradientTape` on a custom training function decorated with `tf.function` instead of Keras' `fit()` method?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to use `@tf.function` on the outer loop, i.e. the 'epoch' loop, it would probably not benefit your model much. It would just make development harder. With more code comes complexity.

However, you must absolutely use `tf.function` on custom loss functions and other functions that get called one every batch.

And, no, using `GradientTape`-d custom `tf.function` would probably not out-perform the keras' fit method. It was thoroughly tested and refined over the years.

Does this answer your questions?